# Vlookup code for a query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 different tabs in a sheet and I want to fetch minimum "Age" along with "Father Name" of the given two duplicate names of children.
You can check left tab as what data look like and right tab for what result I want, In right tab No name will occur twice and I have to fetch only the age with minimum number with VLookup or any other function.

[image: Check This Image for Details]

I tried Vlookup, with min function but I was not getting desired result.

Comment: Sample data should be added as as text, not as image. Also you should show what you have tried and include a brief description of your search efforts for content from this site. Ref. [ask].

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3:A,SORT('TAB1'!A:D,4,1),{4,3},)))
```

- Change ***TAB1*** in the formula to your respective tab name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=LAMBDA(nm,ag,{nm,ag,MAP(nm,ag,LAMBDA(p,q,FILTER(C:C,A:A=p,D:D=q)))})(UNIQUE(A2:A8),BYROW(UNIQUE(A2:A8),LAMBDA(x,MINIFS(D2:D,A2:A,x))))
```

[image]